# Convert 'INFO:' from result query to usable data on airflow

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, airflow

I am trying to use result INFO as conditional, but look the problem

I have this query

```sql
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW mvw_test_2020;
```

This query show me the output:

'INFO:  Materialized view mvw_test_2020 is already up to date.'

But it is not a query result such as `select * from some_table`

I need to get this "INFO" value, to verify if the text is

```
'INFO:  Materialized view mvw_test_2020 is already up to date.'

or

'INFO:  Materialized view mvw_net_mdr_not_stone_2020 was incrementally updated successfully.'

or

'INFO:  Materialized view mvw_net_mdr_not_stone_2020 could not be further updated due to inflight updates.'
```

I need to use this log or query result using xcom or something that I can handle that, on Airflow.

Anyone know any way to handle that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue using this query below:

```sql
with max_date as ( 
      select max(starttime) as max_starttime 
            ,mv_name 
      from SVL_MV_REFRESH_STATUS 
      group by mv_name 
) 
select trim(SVL_MV_REFRESH_STATUS.mv_name) 
      ,starttime 
      ,endtime 
      ,status 
from SVL_MV_REFRESH_STATUS 
inner join max_date on ( 
      starttime = max_date.max_starttime 
      and SVL_MV_REFRESH_STATUS.mv_name = max_date.mv_name 
);
```

Explaining that, we have the first CTE `max_date` to get the last row that contain `mv_name` + `starttime`.

And below we have the query with valuable information doing inner join to the `max_date` cte to get just one line by `mv_name` gettin what I want, LAST UPDATE TO EACH materialized view.